# Consumir via JQuery-Ajax, uma API em localhost:28033, a partir de uma página em localhost:7545

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, cross-domain

Estou tentado fazer uma coisa, mas não está dando certo. Eu tenho dois projetos .Net Core 2.0 , uma API, e um MVC.

Eu quero executar chamadas ajax a partir do projeto MVC, para Controllers do projeto API.

Eu abro dois visual studios, e mando executar dois projetos:

Mando executar o projeto da API:
http://localhost:28033/api/token/autenticar

E mando executar o projeto da Interface AspNetCore MVC
http://localhost:7545/login (Tela de login, que faz a chamada jquery)

Quando eu informo meu email e senha, e clico no botão Entrar, a partir do  localhost:7545, a minha API, que está no http://localhost:28033, responde o seguinte:

```
            UsuarioAutenticado = new UsuarioAutenticado()
            {
                Autenticacao = Autenticacao,
                Token = Token,
                Usuario = Usuario
            };

            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Method", "POST");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

            return Result(UsuarioAutenticado);
```

Quando eu executo pelo Postman, volta o seguinte:

Headers:

access-control-allow-credentials →false

access-control-allow-headers →Content-Type

access-control-allow-method →POST

access-control-allow-origin →*

cache-control →no-cache

content-type →application/json

date →Sat, 07 Jul 2018 01:18:58 GMT

expires →-1

pragma →no-cache

server →Kestrel

transfer-encoding →chunked

Body:

{
    "message": null,
    "isSuccess": true,
    "data": {
        "usuario": {
            "pessoaFisica": null,
            "idPessoaFisica": 1,
            "nomeUsuario": "admin",
            "senha": null,
            "id": 1,
            "dataCriacao": "2018-06-24T20:11:40.99",
            "dataAlteracao": null
        },
        "autenticacao": {
            "idToken": 6,
            "sessionId": "cf3b8d67-4b22-4fc0-b72e-882f77fec078",
            "isAuthenticated": true,
            "id": 17,
            "dataCriacao": "2018-07-06T22:18:58.6775345-03:00",
            "dataAlteracao": null
        },
        "token": {
            "usuario": null,
            "idUsuario": 1,
            "dataExpiracao": "2018-07-06T22:30:09.617",
            "tokenCode": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MzA5MjcwMDksImlzcyI6IlNJTlVDQUJSQVNJTC5DT00uQlIiLCJhdWQiOiJTSU5VQ0FCUkFTSUwuQ09NLkJSIn0.OJnTTGqiPv3mOealCzjd0M2uG_tKVhFY2_Vn77YnINU",
            "isValid": true,
            "id": 6,
            "dataCriacao": "2018-07-06T22:00:09.677",
            "dataAlteracao": null
        }
    }
}

Ou seja, funciona ok.

Mas quando eu coloco minhas informações pelo formulário, e chamo pelo JQuery:

```
    var host = 'http://localhost:28033/api/';

    $("#btnEntrar").on('click', function () {

    try {
        var login = $("#emailLogin").val();
        var senha = $("#passwordLogin").val();
        var lnkEsqueciSenha = $("#lnkEsqueciSenha").val();

        if (login.length == 0) {
            throw "Digite o seu e-mail";
        }

        if (senha.length == 0) {
            throw "Digite a sua senha";
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: host + 'token/autenticar',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { nomeUsuario: login, senha: senha },
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var result = data;

                $("#modalErro").html(result);
                $("#modalErro").show();

                if (!isSuccess) {
                    throw result.message
                }

                $("#btnEntrar").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("#btnEntrar").text('Carregando...');

                window.location = '/';
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $("#modalErro").show();
                $("#modalErro span").text(xhr.responseText);

                $("#btnEntrar").text('Entrar');
                $("#btnEntrar").removeAttr('disabled');
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#btnEntrar").text('Aguarde...');
                $("#btnEntrar").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
            complete: function () {
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        $("#modalErro span").html(e);
        $("#modalErro").show();
    }
});
```

Ele dá um erro no Chrome:

Failed to load http://localhost:28033/api/token/autenticar: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7545' is therefore not allowed access.

Quando eu vejo o header no chrome, vem o seguinte:

Cache-Control: no-cache

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Date: Sat, 07 Jul 2018 01:33:47 GMT

Expires: -1

Pragma: no-cache

Server: Kestrel

Set-Cookie: 
ASPNetCoreSession=CfDJ8KnuUrc2899Bt9ImKJiMxmqcTuiTpwF%2B9cGui15c5yZfjUTRBvsAuwoyRK71gZ5rbpS6Ounjce2fcKUKBR1z1DWDiz9P%2Bykm%2BI39rkU%2BWD5ntbTc8A8e%2B9wy6MV4kKbGDSApTNeLzzCUk19k8SDzDTWplB7ZCRLkJlZf4s0KqV6U; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Ou seja, não voltaram os:

access-control-allow-credentials →false

access-control-allow-headers →Content-Type

access-control-allow-method →POST

access-control-allow-origin →*

Poderiam me orientar, por favor?

Comment: No ajax insira: crossDomain: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eduardo,

Voce precisa habilitar o CORS do .NET Core.

Dentro do Startup do projeto .NET Core dentro do metodo ConfigureServices adiciona:

```
services.AddCors();
```

e dentro do metodo Configure adiciona:

```
app.UseCors(x =>
        {
            x.AllowAnyHeader();
            x.AllowAnyMethod();
            x.WithOrigins(
                "http://localhost:7545",
            );
        });
```

Caso não funcione troque o http://localhost:7545 por um asterisco (*), afim de testes, por que o endereço é a URL da sua aplicação que chama a API. e você pode adicionar múltiplas URL's.

OBS.: Você deve informar sua URL de produção também.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado!